# How to change the title of the button in the user prfile form in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, forms, api, drupal-7

How to change the name of the button in the user_profile_form in drupal 7(From "Save" to "Save All")?
I alter the user profile using this hook:  `hook_form_alter`

```
function userform_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 
      if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form' ) { 

    //I define a submit button like:
    $form['submit'] = array( 
      '#type' => 'submit', 
      '#value' => t('Continue'), 
    );

    //Then I can change it with this code:  
        // Change 'Continue' to 'Sign in'. 
        $form['submit']['#value'] = t('Sign in');

      }
    }
```

It works for all elements(buttons) i define by myself but doesn't work for default button in the user profile form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the devel module enabled, you can run dpm($form) to dump
the form data and then easily locate the element you'd like to alter.

```
function userform_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    // dpm($form);
    if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
        $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = 'Save All';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I guess it possible to change other default fields like timezone? For example to hide it. Where can i read about it?

Comment: If you'll try out dpm($form) and dpm($form_state) as above, you'll see everything contained within the form. From here, it's possibly to reconfigure pretty much anything you'd like to. You can crud fields, create custom validation and/or submit handlers, etc. Once you dpm() one of the objects/arrays, you'll want to reference the Form API: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7

Comment: But how to use dpm($form) and dpm($form_state)?

Comment: If you install the devel module and then implement the code I provided above, you can uncomment the dpm($form) line to view the $form elements.

Comment: The tittle of the button was changed but it doesn't submit anything at all. Why?